# Please add the Ability to add comments in Questions and Answers

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

I have seen this a couple of times. I have come across someones answer and I want to reply back to his answer. Maybe I want to ask something else from the answerer. This could be easily done if there is a comment field after each question and answer.

In this way users can discuss each Q/A like a post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We already have comments, you'll just need to earn a bit more reputation (50) to use them.

See the ["comment everywhere" privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

As [Yannis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/162704/yannis) [said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157710/140449), comments already exists, but they can be used everywhere from who has a reputation of at least 50. Who don't have such reputation can just comment on their own answers (answering to other comments), or the questions they ask (which include any answer posted for their questions).

Keep in mind that comments should be used for specific purposes:

- Request clarification from the author
- Leave constructive criticism to help the author in improving the post
- Add relevant but minor or transient information: a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated

If you want to ask the answer a question, it is probable you should be asking another question, except in the case you want to ask the answerer a clarification about something s/he wrote.

#### References

- [The privilege page for the "comment everywhere" privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment)